# customizing rtl bootstrap5

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

[image: customizing bootstrap]

[image: image that is contain css foldred that is CSS compiled from scss but in ltr dir]

I wanna customize sass file of bootstrap such as padding but in RTL direction but bootstrap doesn't have rtl sass file to change padding and  compile it to RTL CSS file anyone can help me how can do that I don't know how to use rtlcss plugin,image that is contain CSS folder that is CSS compiled from scss but in ltr dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/rtl/) explain how to support RTL.

Basically you need to:

1. Set `dir="rtl"` on the `<html>` element.
2. Add an appropriate `lang` attribute, like `lang="ar"`, on the `<html>` element.
3. You should also use [RTLCSS](https://rtlcss.com/learn/usage-guide/install/). Install it like this:

   ```
   npm install -g rtlcss
   ```

   And after you have compiled the file:

   ```
   $ rtlcss [option option=parameter ...] [source] [destination]
   ```

   Convert for example `input.css` to `output.rtl.css`:

   ```
   > rtlcss input.css output.rtl.css
   ```

   And after compiling, you have an RTL file.